# PostgreSQL: How to store non-compliant (UTF8) raw bytes as bytea using GnuCOBOL?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, gnucobol

The application that I use stores a 32 bit mask (1's and 0's) as a 4 character field in database by converting it to hex. (Its a pretty old application so can't change this).

This used to work well with Oracle & DB2 (UTF8 encoding), however with PostgreSQL (UTF8 encoding) when I try to insert the value using a COBOL program it produces below error:

`ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "SJIS": 0xa0`

`Binary = 01101000001001110000110010100000`

`Hex=0x68270CA0`

Database encoding & table definition

```
diginst=> \encoding
UTF8
diginst=> \d tab_1
 Column |     Type     | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------
 code   | character(5) |           | not null |
 mask   | bytea        |           |          |
```

COBOL Program

```
   IDENTIFICATION              DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.                 ENCODE.
   DATE-WRITTEN.               2013-06-28.
   DATA                        DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE             SECTION.

       EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.
   01  DBNAME                PIC  X(30) VALUE SPACE.
   01  SOC-REC-VARS.
       05  D-CODE             PIC X(5).
       05  D-MASK             PIC X(4).
       EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.

       EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA END-EXEC.

   PROCEDURE                   DIVISION.
   MAIN-RTN.
       MOVE  "/@diginst"         TO   DBNAME.
       EXEC SQL
           CONNECT :DBNAME
       END-EXEC.
       IF  SQLCODE NOT = ZERO DISPLAY "ERROR CONNECTING".
       MOVE "00001" TO D-CODE.
       MOVE X"68270CA0" TO D-MASK.

       EXEC SQL
         INSERT INTO TAB_1
         (CODE,
          MASK)
         VALUES(:D-CODE,
                :D-MASK)
       END-EXEC.
       IF SQLCODE = ZERO DISPLAY "INSERT SUCCESSFUL"
       ELSE DISPLAY "INSERT FAILED " SQLERRMC
            GO TO EXIT-0.
       EXEC SQL
          SELECT CODE,MASK
                 INTO :D-CODE, :D-MASK FROM TAB_1
       END-EXEC.
       IF SQLCODE = ZERO DISPLAY "SELECT SUCCESSFUL"
       ELSE DISPLAY "SELECT FAILED " SQLERRMC.
   EXIT-0.
       STOP RUN.
```

Not sure why it picks the encoding as SJIS even though the client_encoding and server_encoding is UTF8. However, even if it were UTF8 (I manually did SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8' in the above code) 0xA0 is not a valid character in UTF8 character set.

From PostgreSQL documentation on [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)

> In short, binary strings are appropriate for storing data that the
>   programmer thinks of as “raw bytes”, whereas character strings are
>   appropriate for storing text.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong in this case since `bytea` is supposed to work (as per the documentation).

Would also like to know why is the program picking up default encoding as `SJIS` when it should be `UTF8`. I also tried setting the environment variable `PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8` but it still gives the same error as SJIS.

*Didn't think to ask a separate question for this since I believe this too is related to the main problem.

**Update**: after a bit more digging around, DB2 stores raw bytes (even when db encoding doesn't support it) by adding the clause `FOR BIT DATA` in create table statement as-

```
create table tab_db2 (key_part char(5) not null, raw_data char (100) for bit data);
```

In Oracle, the character set used is `AL32UTF8` which supports more characters ([supplementary characters](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514820)) then `UTF8`.

There is [no equivalent](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFm5QJwk3N5%2B5g2whZBUee2jHmNssxO98ybBreDLLUDQHh7zuA%40mail.gmail.com) character set in PostgreSQL for `AL32UTF8` so I have resort to using `LATIN1` for the moment until I find something else.

Comment: What type did you use in Oracle and DB2? What was the *actual* table schema? Both databases have explicit type support for Unicode strings, eg `nvarchar2`. They *don't* need a server encoding to translate `char` to UTF8. The application used a hack that only worked with those specific types. You can't expect it to work the same way in any other database. What were the types?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos DB2 has the definition `CHAR (4)     FOR BIT DATA` and in Oracle the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is AL32UTF8. Not really sure what is the difference between AL32UTF8 and UTF8. Is there an equivalent to AL32UTF8 in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It looks like you've correctly diagnosed your problem - it seems Postgres is validating the string is valid in the character set before converting it to binary. If you were able to change the COBOL to say `05  D-MASK             SQL TYPE is BINARY(4)` or possibly `05  D-MASK              S9(9) BINARY` this may solve it - not a cobol expert though.